# Regular Expression with no final dot pattern

Tags: regex, url, vbscript

I need to evaluate in VBScript Word macro links without selecting a potential ending dot (end of a sentence) such as:

- http://www/foo.com/mypage.php  *(no ending dot)*
- http://www/foo.com/mypage5.php.  *(with ending dot)*

I have set this regex with works fine in a regEx testing page but return a runtime error 5692 on character ^ (is not valid special character for ...)

```vb
pattern = "((http|https)?:\/\/)?([a-z|0-9])([\da-z\/\.-]+)\.(\S*[^\.])"
```

Comment: Does `pattern = "(https?://)?[a-z0-9][\da-z/.-]*\.\S*[^\s.]"` work ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/fvUgOK/1))?

Comment: Nope. Same error :-(

Comment: And `pattern = "(https?://)?[a-z0-9][\da-z/.-]*\.\S*\b`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Pattern

```
(htt.*:\/\/)(.*\/)(.*\.[A-Za-z]+)
```

Will match all kinds of urls ending with only letters and I took the liberty to devide it into 3 capture groups:

1. Protocol - both http / https
2. Domain - any of the following www/foo.bar/ **or** [www.foo.bar/](http://www.foo.bar/) **or** foo.bar/
3. URI - any of the following mypage.php **or** mypage.php.js.python.json **or** .php

#### Explanation

Get string starting with "htt" followed by unlimited amount of characters until encountering "://" and set it as group 1

Continue running for unlimited amount of characters until you hit the first "/" and set this as group 2

Continue once again to run on unlimited amount of characters until you explicitly hit "." followed by unlimited amount of english letters and set it as group 3

#### In your specific example

```
(1) http://www/foo.com/mypage.php
(2) http://www/foo.com/mypage5.php.
```

I've managed to capture the following output:

```
match_1 http://www/foo.com/mypage.php
group_1 http://
group_2 www/foo.com/
group_3 mypage.php
```

```
match_1 http://www/foo.com/mypage5.php
group_1 http://
group_2 www/foo.com/
group_3 mypage5.php
```

Comment: The OP said *"works fine in a regEx testing page"* so the question is more about why they get the Error 5692 in VBScript.

Comment: @user692942 the answer to OP's question is unkonwn to me but I suggested a workaround without using "^" char. Hope it can solve the issue OP is experience